# How to create a side menu in Angular similar to the one on the Wix editor?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, ng-bootstrap

[Wix side menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJw6x.png)

I want to create a similar side menu like the one in the image and later load components into the side panel that opens to the right. It's for a web-editor project.

I tried using ng-bootstrap and Angular Material components but couldn't achieve the desired look. I also don't know how I should structure my components and if I should use a menu, sidebar or another component or not use any libraries at all. I also can't get most Sidenav examples on Angular Material to work.

Answer (score 0):

Check out vanilla Bootstrap sidebars. They have an entire page dedicated to sidebar examples (list items, icons, collapsible, color styling, etc.) that you can effectively copy and paste.

Help installing Bootstrap: [Get Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/introduction/)

Sidebar examples: [Bootstrap Sidebars](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/sidebars/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34774540)